# Как правильно ставить ударение: отрЯдов или отрядОв?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно ставить ударение: отрЯдов или отрядОв?

Answer (score 2):

**ОтрядОв** — это скорее всего **профессиональная речь**, в которой намеренно изменяется ударение.

Например (из Интернета): "Дело **возбУждено**. Когда пришла работать — думала скорее язык себе откушу, чем буду так говорить. Время прошло. Говорю, не откусила".

Вопрос: **А почему в профессиональном жаргоне очень часто слова или отдельные формы меняют ударение?** Обсуждение на форуме [Перемещение ударения в профессиональном жаргоне | lingvoforum.net](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=40217.0)

Answer (score 1):

ОтрЯдов, и знаете, это как-то и недоказуемо... Ибо вариантов не предполагается.

> Русское словесное ударение
>
> искомое слово отсутствует

Comment: На работе коллеги все говорят отрядОв, не знаю почему. А меня это как-то коробит. Мне кажется более правильным отрЯдов

Comment: Анатолий, Вы понимаете, что Словарь ударений молчит, как рыба об лёд, по причине невозможности никакого другого ударения! Коллеги нечто диалектное (быть может) завезли... Говорите правильно; их поправлять не стоит.

Comment: А я так и делаю))

Comment: Работаем в управлении пожарной охраны, в подчинении отряды гос. противопожарной службы республики. Все говорят "начальники отрядОв". А по-моему правильнее говорить "начальники отрЯдов"

Answer (score 1):

**От рядОв говорят, когда имеют в виду ряды, а не отрЯды.** Примеры из нацкорпуса:

*1). Ветер слабо дул с запада, шелестя травой; с ветром нёсся издалёка тонкий, нежный запах свежего сена, но запах шёл не **от рядОв** и копён, а от травы, на корню сохшей под жгучим солнцем. 2). Шлейф возобновления распространяется местами на расстояние до 10 ми более **от рядОв** посадки.*

А в слове **отрЯдов** ударение только на Я.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:отр**Я**дов.

См.:[Грамматический словарь русского языка: Словоизменение. Зализняк А.А. - М.: "АСТ-ПРЕСС", 2008. - 794 с.](http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, буду пользоваться!